# is it possible to make a footer like mentioned below using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, footer

sorry for title but i couldn't find any solution. On the footer of [this site](http://bireysel.bilgeadam.com/bireysel/#) there is a beatiful flash animation of refferencing companies(Google,Cisco, Microsoft ect..). I  want to use a slide like that but i dont know flash at all.. Firstly, what is that tool called,is it possible with jquery(or is there any ready tool for that).. Thanks

**EDIT:** I need them to auto-animate, not needing any user interaction

Comment: Do a google search for "jquery cover flow"

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of options out there, check out this iTunes-like carousel.

http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel

Answer (score 0):

You could build this in Flash, like the example you provided, but to reach more users, you should use javascript instead.

In order to give it that 3D effect where each slide is tilted to the left or right, you could try using [3d transforms](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html) in CSS3.

Edit: If you've got $8, here's [a plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/icarousel/2527180?ref=themespotters&ref=themespotters&clickthrough_id=83645585&redirect_back=true) that does it all for you.